# QuickfixJ-Multileg order - Failed to parse repeated groups

Tags: quickfixj

I am using quickfixj 2.3

Sample aw fix msg :
8=FIX.4.4|9=352|35=AB|...555=2|600=xxx..624=1|600=yyy|...624=2|461=ancd|167=myst|10=150|

Created Message using fix string like: (removed pipes with soh)

Message msg=new Message(rawString);
Session.sendToTarget(msg,sessionId).

I m getting below reason in 58 :
Failed to parse repeated groups: LegOrdGrp(555) at position : 242soh45=11

Comment: You need to use a data dictionary when parsing messages with repeating groups.

Comment: Using the `Message(rawString)` constructor is definitely not a recommended way to do things.  Please review the docs.

Comment: Thanks ,it worked with DD.  So I understand, for repeating groups, we need DD,otherwise normal will work. Right?

Comment: That is correct.

Comment: Great. It worked well for some of orders. However, this parse getting failed for F with repeating groups(Ex: F for Multileg Cancel - where the fix message has F as msg type and 2 legs(repeating groups) . Any other solution for this ?

Comment: Check the definition of the message in the dictionary against what you receive. There most likely is a mismatch.